# How to draw scaled factorial function in processing.js?

Tags: javascript, factorial, processing.js

I have plot function that look like this:

```
var plot_line = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    line(x1+200, -y1+200, x2+200, -y2+200);
};
var plot = function (f, scale) {
    scale = scale || 1;
    for (var x=-200; x<200; x++) {
        var y1 = f(x/scale)*scale;
        var y2 = f((x+1)/scale)*scale;
        plot_line(x, y1, x+1, y2);
    }
};
```

it work fine, it draw function like `function(x) { x*x+2; }` or `Math.sin` but it fail to draw my factorial function:

```
plot(function(x) {
    return factorial(Math.floor(x/10))*10;
}, 1);
```

here is the output:

[image: factorial plot]

and the [demo](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/plot/6405084394553344)

How can I make it look like on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=!x)?

Comment: The Wolfram link you posted is to a graph of the *subfactorial* function.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can copy and paste to run ourselves?